# How to add a empty keyframe in animation tab

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am making an animation on enemy death but the animation doesnt end on an empty frame so the last frame of the animation will remain on the screen. I saw others complete it by making an empty keyframe as the last frame of the animation to make the animation disappear from the screen after the last frame, but i can't find a way to do it.

Wanted effect
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMOjr.jpg
Finding the way to make the last empty keyframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `others manually add` them since there is no such thing like an `empty keyframe`. Sometimes this simply happens e.g. when dealing with sprites see [Why are there extra frames in Unity's Animation System?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/865735/why-are-there-extra-frames-in-unitys-animation-sys.html). I guess it has something to do with the [execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) and rendering order of animators and UI stuff.

However, you could simply create an additional keyframe going to the wanted time and simply double click in the timeline to add a keyframe for all properties with the current state:

[image]

alternatively you can also select all properties for one keyframe by clicking on the keyframe in the grey bar and do <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> - <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to copy the selected keyframes elsewhere.

---

> so the last frame of the animation will remain on the screen

this is actually achieved by simply disabling

`Loop Time`

> Enable to make the animation plays through and then restart when the end is reached.

of the according animation clip

[image]

Comment: the current effect, the last frame remaining on the screen after the animation ended

Answer (score 7):

*A year late, but I found your question while searching for a similar thing. 
Probably you have solved your issue by now. But seeing a question left misunderstood and unanswered bothers me. Anyway, I wanted to add here for others who may come here searching for this.*

- First Adding an extra key-frame at the end, initially with a sprite active.
- Then activate **"Key-frame Recording mode"** (by pressing the red large dot) in
  animation window.
- Be sure that the key-frame that you want empty is selected.
- Go to your Inspector window. Find the **Sprite Render Component**. It
  should have a **"Sprite"** field at the top.
- While "Key-frame Recording mode" active, you set this field to **'none'**
  (by clicking the icon that has a circle with a dot, and selecting the
  first item in the popup).
- Then disable the record mode.

*Without activating record mode, this would revert back to the previous sprite.*

> Of course, as derHugo explained nicely, to make the animation stop at
>   the last (now empty) frame, you also need to click on your animation
>   file in project window and disable "Loop Time" in the inspector.

Comment: Additional clarification: For the "Key-frame Recording mode" button to be active the Animation window must not be maximized. You need to be able to see your Scene or Prefab window as well.  When you are selecting the Sprite Renderer it is associated with the GameObject that your Animator is attached to. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the record method to be a bit cumbersome. What I do is add a Key to the first frame I want the None sprite to be set. The new Key I added was at time zero.

[Image of adding Key to animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkLfF.png)

After saving the changes in the editor I open the .anim file (not the .anim.meta file) in a text editor and search for the relevant path. In my case Body/Cape.

```
- curve:
- time: 0
  value: {fileID: -6465775046297182995, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.05
  value: {fileID: -6465775046297182995, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.06666667
  value: {fileID: 3394640672729110067, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.083333336
  value: {fileID: -4514068313588038808, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.1
  value: {fileID: 7087822514200124772, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
attribute: m_Sprite
path: Body/Cape
```

And I replace the frame at the corresponding time (in my case time of 0) with the None file (fileID of 0):

```
- curve:
- time: 0
  value: {fileID: 0}
- time: 0.05
  value: {fileID: -6465775046297182995, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.06666667
  value: {fileID: 3394640672729110067, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.083333336
  value: {fileID: -4514068313588038808, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
- time: 0.1
  value: {fileID: 7087822514200124772, guid: fda466c51014e1140b1fd77abcc15ca3,
    type: 3}
attribute: m_Sprite
path: Body/Cape
```

Answer (score 0):

Press the red **record** button in the **Animation** tab and disable the Sprite Renderer of your GameObject. Then stop recording by clicking the same button again. This way you animation will disable the sprite renderer and this way make the object invisible. After the end of the animation the Sprite Renderer will be reset automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As described in a couple of the other answers, the UI is so clumsy it is ridiculous. You might have an easier time editing the YAML of the .anim file.

- Add a keyframe at the end.
  It will re-use the last sprite.
- Edit the YAML to set the fileID to 0 for that last keyframe
  (two new lines that have a fileID in the YAML)

This will clear the last sprite.

Here is a screenshot of what the diff should look like:

[image: Diff showing '{fileID: 0}' on the 2 new lines with a fileID]